# How many times have Pokémon actually died of old age?

Tags: pokemon

I was wondering how many times Pokémon have died of old age.

There’s [Stoutland](https://m.bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Stoutland_(anime)) from the anime, but that’s the only time there. In Lavender Town, in one of the retro Pokémon games, there are [graves for Pokémon](https://m.bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Tower). There is also the [Old Cemetery card](https://m.bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Old_Cemetery), but it is unknown if this is for people, Pokémon, or both.

Comment: Kind of related: [Do Pokemon age and die?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/7293/2516)